A/B Testing for component variant
I am creating A/B test for component variant. In experience optimisation when I click on start test its throwing error .
I am able to add test for page content. Tests are visible in active test.
I visit the page multiple times.
But, in reports not showing any update in Best page effect, confidence, Score gained

Please share more information or details of the error.
